# How to tell an rscript report its path/directory when there are multiple nearby copies

Tags: r, batch-file, directory

There are several post related to this subject but none of those solutions (stuff like `source(.., chdir=TRUE)`) seem to work for me. I need an r script that can identify its directory and set the R working directory to this using `setwd()`. In other words the script needs to set the R working directory to the directory where the script is stored. Also there are multiple copies of the script in nearby directories. i.e.

`"../CCurtisModelData/run1/myscript.r"`

`"../CCurtisModelData/run2/myscript.r"`

`"../CCurtisModelData/run3/myscript.r"`

So if myscript is executed from run3 it needs to figure out that its in run3. This code needs to be placed at the beginning of the script so I can set the working directory and load data with relative paths.

I can't use R packages.

I can't rename myscipt i.e. myscript1.r.

My script is executing from a batch file contained in `"../CCurtisModelData/run1"  "../CCurtisModelData/run2"  "../CCurtisModelData/run3"`.

Batch file looks like this. Paths to script are relative.

```
"C:\Users\ccurtis11\Documents\R\R-3.0.1\bin\x64\R.exe" CMD BATCH "myscript.r" "myscript.r.rout"
```

I know I should be using `Rscript` but I got my script working with `CMD` first and I like that I can have it report an .rout file. I'll probably switch to `Rscript` in the future. If switching is not going to help me solve my specific problem here then I'm not interested in switching now.

The only other possible alternative I thought of may be to have a batch file pass directory information to the r script. After consulting with a colleague I'm fairly certain this will work. I'm doing some parallel processing work and am having r handle some data processing for a computer model. So I'm still learning what I an get away with.

So if someone can instruct me on how to pass directory information from the batch file to R that would be great.

It would be much more eloquent however if there was a solution that had the had the r script doing all the work.

The closest I can get is this.

`filenam=list.files("..",full.names=TRUE,recursive=TRUE,pattern="(myscript.r)") 
setwd(dirname(filenam))`

Problem with this is it finds all copies of myscript.r and returns the first i.e "../run1/myscript.r"

Thanks for any idea you pro's can come up with.

Comment: Some info is missing: how do you execute your scripts ? With R, Rscript or source() ?

Comment: Can you have the batch file `cd` into the directory before executing the script? Then have the Rscript use `.` or `getwd()`.

Comment: How about adding `getwd` to your script? oh rats, @flodel ninja'd me by 100 seconds.

Comment: @flodel will `cd` set the working directory of R automatically when the script starts, how would this look in the batch file? I've added new information. @carl I know about `getwd()`. The script needs to find which runner (i.e. run1, run2, run3) it is located in and then `setwd()` that location. much thanks for quick responses guys.

Comment: How are you calling the script?

Comment: @carl I've added that information into the original post.

Answer (score 2):

I just worked this out for some scripts I'm trying to make universally portable.  To ensure portability of your script always begin with:

```
wd <- getwd()
setwd(wd)
```

Assigning the current directory, in the form of a string, to a character object allows you to then insert that character object into setwd() and Presto your code will always run with its current directory as the working directory, no matter whose machine it is on or where in the file structure it is located. (Extra bonus: The wd object can be used with file.path() (ie. file.path(wd, "output_directory") to allow for the creation of a standard output directory regardless of the file path leading to your named directory. This does require you to make the new directory before referencing it this way but that, too, can be aided with the wd object.

(I'm aware I posted this answer for another, nearly identical question.  I'm not trying to milk this answer for points, I'm just trying to work through these existing questions for a related issue I'm having with auto-locating the RScript executable (remote system) and auto-setting its file path.)

Answer (score 1):

Ok I feel bad for posting an answer to my own question but I figured if it might help someone out down the line its worth it.

Turns out the fact that I was using `R CMD` was really holding me back.

Once I switched over to `Rscript` the first solution I retried worked. Nice thing is I can still have my r.out file.

my.bat

`"C:\Users\ccurtis11\Documents\R\R-3.0.1\bin\x64\Rscript.exe" myscript.r > myscript.r.rout`

myrscript:

`args <- commandArgs(trailingOnly = F)`

`scriptPath <- normalizePath(dirname(sub("^--file=", "", args[grep("^--file=", args)])))`

`setwd(scriptPath)`

`getwd()`

I added `getwd()`so I could check that it was working by looking at the myscript.r.rout file but `getwd` isn't needed.

Comment: Nothing wrong with posting a solution.  First of all, we get to congratulate you for doing the work; second, it may inspire someone to use this in similar situations.